# left itemize in third column of table

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, itemize

I am having problems with getting my itemize in my table to be vertical aligned. Can anyone help me out?

This is the code i am using:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{What map to be used depending on the level of scope \cite{Process_map_theory}.}
\label{maps}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Level of scope} & \textbf{Map to be used}  & \textbf{Key features}\\ 
    \hline
    Organisation  & Relationship map &  \tabitem Supplier-Organisation-costumer interactions.\\
            & &   \tabitem Key sections of the organisation. \\
            & & \tabitem Supplier-costumer supply chain.\\ 
   \hline
    Process  &  Cross-functional process map  &    \tabitem  Swimlane of the process.  \\
            & &  \tabitem Workflow of the process.  \\
            & &    \tabitem Supplier-costumer interactions. \\
     \hline
    Job/Performer  & Process map &    \tabitem Value adding time of the system.  \\
            & &    \tabitem Non value adding time of the system. \\
      \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable. e.g. How is `\tabitem` defined?

Comment: Please also specify what "vertical aligned"  refers to in this situation. Perhaps a sketch of the desired output would help clarify your question.

Comment: A random guess: Is `\begin{tabular}{|c|c|l|}` what you are looking for?

Comment: by vertical aligned i mean to have all the items in the third column straight aligned to the left of the column. Right now they are centered in the columne and therefor not aligned since they have different length. 

How do i make the code compatible?

i Tried \begin{tabular}{|c|c|l|} but i get an error (do i need a package for this?)

Comment: I use this:

\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}

Comment: If I combine all the information you alrady offered into a small document, `\begin{tabular}{|c|c|l|}` works perfectly fine. This does not need any additional packages. Since this does not seem to work in your case, please prepare a small example ocument that others can reproduce your problem. It would also be helpful to know, which error message exactly you get.

Comment: error: Illegal pream token (1): `c' used.

Comment: Another guess: Did you add the number 1 (`1`)  instead of the letter l (`l`)? In `\begin{tabular}{|c|c|l|}` you should have the letter c twice and then the letter l. By the way, `c` corresponds to a **c**entered column, `l` to a **l**eft aligned column.

Comment: Yes, this was the problem, thank you very much. Very funny haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather use list instead of `\tabitem`s and `tabularx` table environment (now your table spill out of text area):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{%
    \setlist[itemize]{nosep,     % <-- table's list setup
                      leftmargin = *         ,
                      label      = $\bullet$ ,
                      before     = \vspace{-0.6\baselineskip},
                      after      = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
                        }
                           }% end of AtBeginEnvironment

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{What map to be used depending on the level of scope \cite{Process_map_theory}.}
\label{maps}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|X|
                                >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.45\linewidth}|}
    \hline
\textbf{Level of scope} & \textbf{Map to be used}  & \textbf{Key features}  \\
    \hline
Organisation    & Relationship map  &   \begin{itemize}
                                    \item Supplier-Organisation-costumer interactions.
                                    \item Key sections of the organisation. 
                                    \item Supplier-costumer supply chain.
                                        \end{itemize}                       \\
   \hline
Process     &  Cross-functional process map  
                                    &   \begin{itemize}
                                    \item Swimlane of the process.  
                                    \item Workflow of the process.  
                                    \item Supplier-costumer interactions. 
                                        \end{itemize}                       \\
    \hline
Job/Performer  & Process map        &   \begin{itemize}
                                    \item Value adding time of the system.  
                                    \item Non value adding time of the system. 
                                        \end{itemize}                       \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]